# What is a Resource Federation Server?

Tags: adfs

I have been reading about Federated Services, specifically Microsoft's ADFS server. I noticed that in some network diagrams they use something called "Resource Federation Server". However, I'm not very clear what that is for.

I have used ADFS 2.0 Server to authenticate against Active Directory for users on my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Resource STS" or "RP-STS" or "Federation Provider" are all close relatives for an STS (such as ADFS) that sits between apps and "Identity Providers" (IdP). They are in essence intermediaries between consumers of tokens (like apps) and issuers of tokens.

Among the common tasks and responsibilities:

- They perform token transformation (they transform tokens in differetn formats and with different content) into something that the consumers understand.
- Protocol transition: the handle one protocol on one side (e.g. WS-Federation) and another one on the other (e.g. SAMLP)

So in summary they are an STS that are often associated with a "resource" (e.g. a "relying party") and isolate them from the details of the other STSs that might not be compatible or that might be out of reach from an administrative perspective. (They belong to a different company in federation scenario).

Logically:

App -> R-STS -> IdP

An example:

|--Your company--------|  |Google|

Your app -> ADFS -> ACS -> Google

SharePoint, as another example, ships with an embedded STS that is technically a "Resource STS", where the resource is SP.